General declaration in UserForm, Excel
How’s going? I’am a beginner in VBA and I have been try to figure it out how to do it the following question, but I just can’t. So, I will explain my struggle in VBA and hopefully you guys can have a solution.
I have a userform with 3 Opttion Buttons. I have a code for each Opption Button and they are pretty similar. In my workflow, I need to duplicate the userforms, cause, basically, I will use the same structure everytime, but in different cells. I will post a pic so you guys can understand better. The following pic is the code of one of the opption buttons:
First pic
So far, so good, the code works just as exactly is supposed to be. But, since I need do duplicate the UserForms, cause I will use the same strutucture in others cells, it will be easier if I have some general declaration that will be applied in all the opptions buttons that my Userform has, working like a “global variable” for all the opptions buttons that my userform has. So, what I was trying to do is:
Second pic
When I declare general variables like the pic above, the code crashs to recognize “set Rng1 = Range(“AK5”)”. So, you guys know how to solve this problem? I guess it’s not that complicate, I’m just not knowing how to declare general declarations in Userform. I will post the codes of each opption button below:
**OptionButton1:**
'Where it's going to copy
Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("AK5")

'Where it's going to past
Dim Rng2 As Range
Set Rng2 = Range("H24")

'Name Userform
Dim myUF As Object
Set myUF = zzzz22

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rng1.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rng2.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload myUF
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Select



**OptionButton2:**
'Where it's going to copy
Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("AK5")

'Where it's going to past
Dim Rng2 As Range
Set Rng2 = Range("H24")

'Name Userform
Dim myUF As Object
Set myUF = zzzz22

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Rng1.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rng2.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload myUF
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Select



**OptionButton 3:**
'Where it's going to copy
Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("AK5")

'Where it's going to past
Dim Rng2 As Range
Set Rng2 = Range("H24")

'Name Userform
Dim myUF As Object
Set myUF = zzzz22

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rng1.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rng2.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload myUF
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Select

The way I have my workflow, everytime I duplicate a new userform, I will have to change the value of the cells for each opption button. If I manage to have a general declaration that will be applied for the three opptions buttons, my workflow will be much faster, since I will only have to change the cells of the general declaration, and that will be applied as well for each option button all at once.
Hope I made myself clear, if you guys have a question about something, I will be answering. Thanks for your attention!!

Executable code like Set... needs to be in a method (sub, function, property) so you can't have that type of code at the same level as your global declarations.  FYI in the userform code module you can use Me to refer to the running userform instance - eg Unload Me

You can instead put something like this in your declarations at the top of the module Const RNG_1 As String = "AK5" then in your event code Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range(RNG_1)

It could be structured like this, using constants for the range addresses:
Const RNG_1 As String = "AK5"
Const RNG_2 As String = "H24"

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(RNG_1).Copy .Range(RNG_2)
        .Shapes("Rectangle 2").Select
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub


Thank you so much for your reply! It actually work, but the cell can not be merge, otherwise, it will not work. Do you know some otherway to make this code work with merge cells?

Do you get an error message? Which cells are merged?  Do you only need to copy values, or do you also need to copy formatting?

Yes, i'm received the following message "we cannot do this in a merge cell". I only need to copy values from one range to another, but the cell I'm pasting these values has conditional formatting and merge cells

I just figure it out how to do it. I only need to put the reference of the cells that are merged e.g:
Const RNG_1 As String = "AK5"
Const RNG_2 As String = "H24:M24"

Thank you so much for your attention Tim, my workflow will be a lot faster with the code you just posted, you really help me!! I'm going to run some tests here, but I really think that should be enough
